# Gulp plugin for checking number of SCSS classes

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

this is more of a general question/guidance thing.

I'm using Gulp 3.x with a `gulpfile.js` along with `gulp-sass` & `gulp-watch` and some other Gulp plugins. What I'm looking to do is to be able to scan all my SCSS files and pick out the number of classes etc and then setup a task whereby if the total number of classes drops below X (as an example, someone tries to remove large chunks of styling) it would then throw an error.

Does anyone know of a package or what I need to look for to achieve this. I'm using NPM.

Comment: It can be achieved relatively easily by writting PostCSS plugin

Comment: @Flying I'm using Gulp & SCSS, not PostCSS. Do you have an example?

Comment: I've added answer with proposed solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [cssstats](https://github.com/cssstats/postcss-cssstats) plugin for [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/). It [can be](https://github.com/cssstats/postcss-cssstats#usage-with-gulpjs) used in Gulp and its [result](https://github.com/cssstats/core#returned-object) seems to contain all information that you want to.